# Protractor issue with getting expect to find element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Quite a basic test but is returning

× Invited contributor is made into a company owner
      - Failed: owner.$(...).isDisplayed(...).toBe is not a function

basically I have a table which displays the owners and contributors to the site, when someone is an owner an element becomes visible on that row of the table. I know this function works for selecting and making the person an owner, but when trying to set an expect it gives an error. Is there some other way to do the check on the owner variable?

```
it('Invited contributor is made into a company owner', function() {
        settingsPage.promoteContributorToOwner();

        var owner = element.all(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners')).filter(function(rowElement){
            return rowElement.element(by.css('td[ng-bind="existingOwner.Name"]')).getText().then(function(text){
                return text.trim() == 'protractor contributor'
            });
        }).first();
        expect(owner.$('i[title="Site Owner"]').isDisplayed().toBe('true'));

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simply a question of misplaced parentheses. You're actually attempting to call `toBe()` on the value returned by `isDiplayed()` instead of on the object returned by `expect()`. So by moving the last parenthesis a bit backwards, this should work as expected *(pun intended)*:

```
expect(owner.$('i[title="Site Owner"]').isDisplayed()).toBe('true');
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. Amazing what another pair of eyes can do!